# Poor performance when using MonoTouch's HttpWebRequest

Tags: xamarin.ios, httpwebrequest

I'm downloading some small images (about 40 KB each) in my MonoTouch app. The images are downloaded in parallel - the main thread creates the requests and executes them asynchronously.

I use `WebRequest.Create` to create the HTTP request, and in the completion handler, I retrieve the response stream using `response.GetResponseStream()`. Then, the following code reads the data from the response stream:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int read;
while ((read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

When downloading only one image, this runs very fast (50-100 milliseconds, including the wait for the web request). However, as soon as there are several images, say 5-10, these lines need more than 2 seconds to complete. Sometimes the thread spends **more than 4 second**. Note that I'm not talking about the time needed for `response.BeginGetResponse` or the time waiting for the callback to run.

Then I tested the following code, it needs less than 100 milliseconds in the same scenario:

```
var ms = new MemoryStream();
responseStream.CopyTo(ms);
```

**What's the reason for this huge lag in the first version?**

The reason I need the first version of the code is that I need the partially downloaded data of the image (specially when the image is bigger). To isolate the performance problem, I removed the code which deals with the partially downloaded image.

I ran the code in Debug and Release mode in the simulator as well as on my iPad 3, and I tried both compiler modes, LLVM and non-LLVM. **The lag was there in all configurations, Debug/Release, Device/Simulator, LLVM/non-LLVM.**

Comment: Never mind, we're using `NSUrlConnection`s now, works much much better.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it is a limitation in the number of concurrent http network connections:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint.connectionlimit.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hello maybe not the direct answer to your question but have you tried [SDWebImage](https://components.xamarin.com/view/sdwebimage/) from [Xamarin Component Store](https://components.xamarin.com)? This is an amazing library developed by [Olivier Poitrey](https://github.com/rs) that out of the box provides asynchronous image downloader, memory + disk image caching and some other benefits, it is really nice.

Hope this helps

Alex